# JavaScript while loop through a video while automatically playing and pausing

Tags: javascript

How can I efficiently write a JavaScript while loop code to automatically play a one hour video while playing for three seconds and pausing for six seconds to allow me time to transcribe? This is what I have tried but I have not succeeded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


    <head>  
        <title> Video transcription</title>
    </head> 
    <body> 

    </body>
        <video id = 'myVideo' >
            <source src = 'testVideo.mp4'>
            </video>
   <script>

var pauseTime = 6000 // six seconds
var initialTime = 0
var timeUpdate = 3
var timeIncrement = initialTime + timeUpdate
var wasPausedBefore1 = 0;
var wasPausedBefore2 = 0;
var wasPausedBefore3 = 0;


while (video.duration > 0) {
    var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
    video.play();
    video.ontimeupdate = function() {
        let currentTime =video.currentTime;
        if (currentTime > initialTime && currentTime < timeIncrement && wasPausedBefore1 == 0) {
    video.pause();
            wasPausedBefore1 = 1;
            setTimeout(function() {
        video.play();
            }, pauseTime);
        } else if(currentTime > initialTime && currentTime < timeIncrement && wasPausedBefore2 == 0){
    video.pause();
            wasPausedBefore2 = 1;
            setTimeout(function() {
        video.play();
            }, pauseTime);

        } 
        initialTime += timeUpdate
        timeIncrement += timeUpdate    
    }

}
   </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to create a control logic of your application:

1. Created a Petri Net diagram of the control logic. I used Notepad to create the diagram as PDF form XObject.
2. Created an interactive prototype of the control logic as a PDF form application.
3. Created the control logic of the application based on the prototype. I used the setTimeout API instead of a loop structure.

For me this is an effective way to create the control logic of many applications because creating the interactive prototype based on a Petri Net diagram is a systematic activity.

The interactive prototype plus details on its construction and additional sample source codes are available in a dynamic and interactive PDF at https://www.academia.edu/43005182/How_to_Automatically_Play-and-Pause_a_Video_A_Reply_to_a_Request_at_Stack_Overflow.

The following HTML code is an example of how to use the control logic.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Play-and-Pause Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <video id = 'video0'>
    <source src = '1956Pepto_512kb.mp4'>
  </video>
  <script>
    /* Copyright 2020 John Frederick Chionglo */
    var tObject;
    var vTime = 64000;
    var vID = document.getElementById('video0');

    function PlayAndPause(parms) {
      this.videoID = parms.videoID;
      this.videoTime = parms.videoTime;
      this.tObject = undefined;
    }
    PlayAndPause.objs = [];
    PlayAndPause.play = function(id) {
      PlayAndPause.objs[id].playSegment(id);
    };
    PlayAndPause.pause = function(id) {
      PlayAndPause.objs[id].pauseSegment(id);
    };
    with (PlayAndPause) {
      prototype.window = this;
      prototype.playTime = 3000;
      prototype.pauseTime = 6000;
      prototype.playSegment = function(id) {
        this.videoID.play();
        this.videoTime -= this.playTime;
        this.tObject = setTimeout("PlayAndPause.pause("+ id + ")", this.playTime);
      };
      prototype.pauseSegment = function(id) {
        if (this.videoTime<0) {}
        else {
          this.videoID.pause();
          this.tObject = setTimeout("PlayAndPause.play(" + id + ")", this.pauseTime);
        }
      };
    }
    var ppobj = new PlayAndPause({videoID: vID, videoTime: vTime});
    PlayAndPause.objs[0] = ppobj;
    ppobj.playSegment(0);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```